# Admin account suddenly doesn't have permission to do anything files related

Tags: macos, permission

I don't know what happened, or what I've done really but all of a sudden I tried to move a file from the downloads folder to the documents folder and it says "You can put items into Documents but you won't be able to see them. Other users with sufficient permissions will be able to use the items."

And after following some advices onlines, I deleted every other account on the mac besides mine which is an admin account, added it to the wheel group and tried to give read & write access to the whole HDD but same issue, I don't have enough permission.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

To answer Allan,
MacOs Version: **MacOs Big Sur 11.4**.

This never happened before, it might have something to do with the fact that I needed to do something with my main macbook account and so I created a new admin account, gave my main account more access I think, and deleted the admin account. Now my main account is admin but with no permission.

It also happens with the `Desktop` folder as well and yes I basically only really have CRUD freedom with the `Downloads` folder.

Yes I checked in the Users & Groups, I checked and re-checked.

EDIT:

When I go to `/Users` I get `Shared` and `anon` which is my current admin account, here's the output:

```
drwxrwxrwt   8 root  wheel   256B Mar 31  2022 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 82 anon  staff   2.6K Jun  1 15:46 anon
```

Comment: Welcome!  We’re going to need some key details like what version of macOS you’re running, whether this happened before,  if this also happens with other folders (i.e. Desktop), if your Mac is managed by your company, etc.  Are you certain you have Admin rights?  Can you verify?  Please updated your question with an [edit] so that we can better help you.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Each user has their own Downloads, Desktop etc. It sounds like you're still trying to use the old folders, when as a new user you now have your own. As an admin, you can in fact add yourself to the old ones - but check the hierarchy first & see if it's not just easier to move to the new ones. Start at your 'Macintosh HD' level in column view & look at Users...

Comment: The source of the problem is probably all this altering of default user access that you've done, which shouldn't be necessary. Can we see Terminal output of the attributes on one of these files? I'm guessing that the files are owned by a user that you've deleted.

Comment: That's really what it was, I replaced the sidebar Documents and Desktop with the ones from /Users/anon and it now works just like before, but I still can't set MacintoshHD -> Get Info -> Sharing and Permissions -> Add admin account or wheel group as Read & Write, but maybe I shouldn't, but in any case the admin account should be able to do everything it wants right ?